# Type of Distribution for Survey Answers 1 to 10

Tags: probability, data-analysis

I'm investigating survey data where participants are asked to answer based on a scale of 1 to 10

typically, the average is around 8.5 with most responses between 7-10, with a lower numbers like 3 scattered around

what is the best way to describe the distribution since it's skewed?  I would stay away from using standard deviation since it's clearly not normal, but obviously some are distributed differently than others and I would like to quantitatively capture that

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at a multinomial distribution I think.  Since you can look at each number 1-10 as a different category, and each category $p_k, k=1,...,10$ gets a particular probability, it definitely sounds a if we are dealing with the multinomial distribution.

We know it is not normal since it is a discrete distribution.  But multinomial discrete has the multivariable normal as its counterpart in the continuous case.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution